# Authenticating to ACR1255U through Bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to authenticate to the [ACR1255U](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/403/acr1255u-j1-bluetooth%C2%AE-nfc-reader/) using a [BLED112](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bled112-bluetooth-smart-dongle/) through Bluetooth. I have tried sending the commands frames `6B 00 05 00 00 00 CB E0 00 00 45 00` and `05 00 0C 6B 00 05 00 00 00 CB E0 00 00 45 00 0C 0A` to the `FFF1` characteristic but get no response. I have tried setting up the notifications on the `FFF2` characteristic by writing the value `0x0003` to the client characteristic configuration (`0x2902`), but receive an error.

Which is the correct command frame to start authentication for the ACR1255U and how do you setup notifications on the ACR1255U?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was able to figure it out:

To setup notifications on the `FFF2` characteristic, write the value `0x0100` to the client characteristic configuration. The value was in little-endian order which was causing me trouble

The correct frame to start authentication is `05 00 0C 6B 00 05 00 00 00 CB E0 00 00 45 00 0C 0A`, which must be written to the `FFF1` characteristic.

**You must setup notifications before sending commands in order to get a response**